# What is FreeBSD equivalent of Linux /etc/gshadow?

Tags: freebsd, group

FreeBSD version 9.0 I have here.

It has `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` files as Linux does.
I figured that Linux `/etc/shadow` corresponds to FreeBSD `/etc/master.passwd`.
The open question is what FreeBSD uses in place of Linux `/etc/gshadow` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FreeBSD doesn't have an equivalent. The convention is not to use group passwords at all and just put an asterisk in the password field. No group passwords means no need to have something like /etc/gshadow.